# webcam is continuously active and running , how to close webcam?

Tags: python

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
camera=cv.VideoCapture(0)

while True:

    _, frame=camera.read()
    
    cv.imshow('original',frame)
    
    laplacian=cv.Laplacian(frame,cv.CV_64F)
    laplacian=np.uint8(laplacian)
    cv.imshow('laplacian',laplacian)
    
    
    edges=cv.Canny(frame,150,100)
    
    cv.imshow('edged',edges)
    
    if cv.waitKey(1) ==ord('x'):
        break
    
camera.release()
```

Comment: You close the webcam by closing the application.  Press 'x'.  Do you just want to grab one image and then stop?  If so, then why do you have a `while` loop at all>

Comment: Is this specific to `cv2`? I've never used it myself. If it is, please add the relevant tag(s). BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I got it , I resolved my problem , Thank you Tim Roberts , Actually I'm the new to stackoverflow ,this is my first question  ,thanks everyone